How can I achieve this particular resizing behavior?
I am trying to achieve a certain resizing behavior in the footer of an application, which has the following general xaml structure:
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        ... 

        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="2,0" Content="Checkbox" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Log Folder: " />

            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="2" Focusable="False" IsReadOnly="True" Cursor="Hand" Text="{Binding LogFolder}" />

            <Button Grid.Column="3" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="4,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SelectFolderCommand}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Images/Refresh.png" />
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>

            <Button Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content=" Button " />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

In the footer, the text box is truncated if there isn't enough horizontal space to display the whole path:

When there is more than enough space, the text box expands horizontally to fill the available space:

While the former behavior is desired, I would like the text box to not expand to fill the entire available space in the latter case. Rather, I would like the text box to expand just enough to display the entire path, and then have the left button remain adjacent to it, with any excess space appearing between the two buttons, like in this mock-up:

I've tried wrapping the text box and left button in a nested grid like this:
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="2,0" Content="Checkbox" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Log Folder: " />

    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="2" Focusable="False" IsReadOnly="True" Cursor="Hand" Text="{Binding LogFolder}" />

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="4,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SelectFolderCommand}">
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Images/Refresh.png" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Button Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content=" Button " />
</Grid>

While this does achieve the desired behavior when there is more than enough space, when there isn't enough space the left button is overrun:

Beyond this, I've tried numerous other permutations of swapping the Auto and * widths for the Grids' columns, wrapping things in StackPanels, docking things in DockPanels, and adding further Grids, but I can only ever achieve one of the two previously described sets of behavior. I.e. either the left button doesn't get overrun when the window is narrow but the text box expands without bound when the window is wide, or the text box's expansion is bounded when the window is wide but the left button gets overrun when the window is narrow.
Is the behavior I'm looking for achievable? Pure-xaml answers preferred, but if I can only achieve this via code in the codebehind, the viewmodel, or a converter, so be it.

Nested Grids as you already have will work as expected.
You just have to make sure to set HorizontalAlignment="Left" on the inner Grid, and use column widths * and Auto in that order.
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Content="Checkbox" Padding="2,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Log Folder: " />

    <Grid Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Height="24" Padding="2"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Focusable="False"
            IsReadOnly="True" Cursor="Hand" Text="{Binding LogFolder}" />

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="4,0"
            Command="{Binding SelectFolderCommand}">
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Images/Refresh.png" />
        </Button>

    </Grid>

    <Button Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content=" Button " />
</Grid>


Wow, it was that simple. I had been assuming that HorizontalAlignment="Left" was the default for everything and didn't bother trying that.

The default value of HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment is Stretch.

Ah, I see. I had been conflating TextAlignment with HorizontalAlignment. Thanks for the knowledge!

You can use proxy elements to measure and set the size.
Look at this example:
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="2,0" Content="Checkbox" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Log Folder: " />

        <FrameworkElement Grid.Column="2" x:Name="sizeSource"/>
        <FrameworkElement Grid.Column="3"
                            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Margin="{Binding Margin, ElementName=btnSource, Mode=OneWay}"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="2" Focusable="False" Cursor="Hand"
                        MinWidth="40" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=sizeSource, Mode=OneWay}"/>

            <Button x:Name="btnSource" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="4,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SelectFolderCommand}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Source/CenterPicture.png" />
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content=" Button " />
    </Grid>


This seems to work! I like this trick, and will try to keep it in mind. Thanks! I'll accept this in due time if no better answers appear.

I have to admit I am surprised that binding the FrameworkElement in column 3 by ElementName to btnSource works.  I always thought that ElementName was only supposed to work when the element to which you were referring had already been defined previously.

@Joe
Binding ElementName provides dynamic binding. For example, you can reassign FrameworkElement.RegisterName(String, Object) at runtime at any time during the Window's lifetime and the value of Binding ElementName will be re-evaluated.
