Size control by available space, not contents
Right now I'm having this problem with controls that can display variable data of indeterminate size. For example, a TextBox displaying a long file path or a ListBox displaying error messages. This may be relevant to other controls but these are the two specific ones I'm wrestling with now.
Basically, I want these controls to expand to fill available space (growing and shrinking if the window itself is resized), but I don't want their contents to influence their size at all. Right now when I use a Textbox, if I give it text larger than it's size it will expand to fit the contents and force the window to be bigger. This is not what I want.
One solution I came up with is to inherit a new class from TextBox (NonBloatingTextBox) override the MeasureOverride function, but this seems like an unnecessarily crude way to do something that I feel should already be doable.
I use mostly DockPanels, Grids, and StackPanels for layout, so I don't rely on fixed positioning. In some of my windows I have them resizable, but others I turn off resizing and make them SizeToContent. I would like this solution to work for both situations.
Is there an existing way in WPF to make controls expand and contract to fill available space, but not force expansion based on their contents?

I've tried Horizintal/Vertical Alignment = Stretch settings in various ways, but I honestly don't even know what effect that setting has on the various layout panels so I don't even know if I'm doing this right or wrong.
Reference code for the NonBloatingTextBlock I mentioned. This has seemed to work all the times I've used it, but it seems like this should be built-in functionality and not a kludge.
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public class NonBloatingTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        return MinimumDesiredSize;
    }

    #region Private static properties
    private static Size MinimumDesiredSize { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region static constructor
    public NonBloatingTextBox()
    {
        MinimumDesiredSize = base.MeasureOverride(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    }
    #endregion
}

ETA: Here are two screenshots showing the behavior in question. The text at the bottom is showing the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of the control so you can see the width difference between the two. What I want, concretely, is for the second one to be the exact same width as the first. I want the ListBox to expand to the entire width of the available space, but I don't want the contents to forcefully widen the window like it does now.


And for reference, here is the entire WPF of my control. It's a UserControl that placed as the only content of a Window when shown. The only custom controls are the NonBloatingTextBox I already posted, and ControlPadding, which just inherits from Border and does nothing else so I can put consistent spacing between widgets and control that spacing with a Style without screwing up internal Borders that other controls are made of.
<UserControl
    x:Class="MovimentoRegistration.MovimentoRegistrationControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controlslib="clr-namespace:ControlLibrary;assembly=ControlLibrary"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MovimentoRegistration"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="controlslib:ControlPadding">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,5" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <controlslib:ControlPadding>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="200" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Label>License Status:</Label>
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Label>User Name:</Label>
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Label>Machine Name:</Label>
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Label>PCID:</Label>
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="controlslib:ControlStack">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LicenseIsValid, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="ActivePage" Value="0" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LicenseIsValid, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="ActivePage" Value="1" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DockPanel.Resources>
                        <controlslib:ControlStack>
                            <Label controlslib:ControlStack.PageIndex="0" Foreground="Green">Valid</Label>
                            <Label controlslib:ControlStack.PageIndex="1" Foreground="Red">Invalid</Label>
                        </controlslib:ControlStack>
                    </DockPanel>
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <controlslib:NonBloatingTextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValidationInfo.MachineInfo.UserName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                    <controlslib:NonBloatingTextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValidationInfo.MachineInfo.MachineName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                    <controlslib:NonBloatingTextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValidationInfo.MachineInfo.PCID, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </controlslib:ControlPadding>
            </Grid>
            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" LastChildFill="True">
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MovimentoRegistrationControl}}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" x " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MovimentoRegistrationControl}}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <controlslib:ControlPadding>
                        <Button Click="RecheckLicenseButton_Click">Recheck License</Button>
                    </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                    <controlslib:ControlPadding>
                        <Button Click="SaveRegistrationFileButton_Click">Save Registration File</Button>
                    </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                </StackPanel>
                <controlslib:ControlPadding />
            </DockPanel>
            <controlslib:ControlPadding>
                <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=ValidationErrors.Count}" HeaderStringFormat="{}Validation Failures: {0}">
                    <controlslib:ControlPadding>
                        <ListView
                            MinHeight="50"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ValidationErrors, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </controlslib:ControlPadding>
                </GroupBox>
            </controlslib:ControlPadding>
        </DockPanel>
    </controlslib:ControlPadding>
</UserControl>



If you want the TextBox to grow to fit available space, you should, (as you have tried) set its HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties to Stretch.  But if you do not want the Window contains them to be forced to grow according to the size of the TextBox it contains, then set the Height and Width properties of that window (or of the root panel element you have placed within it).  You can even set the MaxHeight and MaxWidth properties.

A good way to test the effects of these things is with the Visual Designer.  Make a simple layout and start altering properties and see what happens.

I want the controls to resize themselves if the available space changes, such as the user manually resizing the window. Manually setting Height and Width doesn't allow that.

You think I haven't played around in Designer multiple times by now? I'll admit I'm far from an expert, but this has been my job for a few years now so I do have some knowledge of how things work. The reason I ask here is because I couldn't figure it out on my own, either through playing around or searching.

You don't set the Height and width of the controls.  You merely set their alignment properties.  Those alignment properties are hints to the panel that contains them as to how they want to be laid out.  You set the height and width of the panel that contains them when you resize it and it is responsible for laying out those controls according to their alignment properties.

There are many ways to implement what you have in mind. Here is an example of an "XAML only" implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78949848/
